# Nmap scan is not showing all devices in my network

Tags: networking, linux, nmap

I have an Android device that runs Android9 and also another Android device that runs Android6 on it. I shared Android9's internet to Android6 through a wifi connection. Then I shared the Android6's internet to my computer (runs linux) through `USB Tethering` option. Then on my computer, I run the command `sudo nmap -sn <my_network_address>`

It only showed my Android6's ip address and my computer's ip address. It does not show my Android9 on that list.

I want to know why do this happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Information security within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection sharing is likely made on android with NAT.

So the devices are on different networks, and are not seen by the *nmap* scan.

For example:

- the computer is using `192.168.43.0/24`
- android6 is using `192.168.1.0/24`
- android9 isusing `10.1.2.0/32`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I don't know what causes this problem. But for me, I had to retry hitting the same command to get active devices. But I believe there're other options which I'm missing.

My First try>>

```
➜  ~ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.11.0/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-08 08:57 +0545
Nmap scan report for x-ubuntu20 (192.168.11.64)
Host is up.
Nmap scan report for x-ubuntu20 (192.168.11.67)
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 11.63 seconds
```

My Second try>>

```
➜  ~ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.11.0/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-08 08:58 +0545
Nmap scan report for _gateway (192.168.11.254)
Host is up (0.0015s latency).
MAC Address: 88:B3:XX:XX:XX:XX (Nokia Shanghai Bell)
Nmap scan report for x-ubuntu20 (192.168.11.64)
Host is up.
Nmap scan report for x-ubuntu20 (192.168.11.67)
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 10.72 seconds
```

My Third try>>

```
➜  ~ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.11.0/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-08 08:58 +0545
Nmap scan report for 192.168.11.66
Host is up (0.028s latency).
MAC Address: AC:5A:XX:XX:XX:XX (Samsung Electronics)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.11.68
Host is up (0.032s latency).
MAC Address: D8:1E:XX:XX:XX:XX (Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications)
Nmap scan report for _gateway (192.168.11.254)
Host is up (0.00083s latency).
MAC Address: 88:B3:XX:XX:XX:XX (Nokia Shanghai Bell)
Nmap scan report for x-ubuntu20 (192.168.11.64)
Host is up.
Nmap scan report for x-ubuntu20 (192.168.11.67)
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 8.61 seconds
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the problem but got a solution.

the first thing is to set the VM to bridge and chech the ifconfig

after checking my IP of the VM is in the same as other devices, I use nmap with the -PN (to force ping)

real example:
nmap 192.168.1.1-200 -sn -Pn

so I scanned all 200 hosts, devices that were not showing appeared after -Pn